# Can I perform SQL query in table based on user input?

Tags: python, sqlite

So, I am new to Stackoverflow and I hope I'm writing this question well. So I'm trying to choose a table from my database (that contains 5 tables) based on user input in python. However I'm not quite sure how to do it. Here is the code:

```
user_input = "table1"
db.execute("SELECT number FROM (?) WHERE person = 1;")
```

I'm searching for a way if it is possible. Anyway any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Comment: As noted in the duplicate, it is not possible to pass the tablename as a parameter, so your only option is query building (like in the answer you got), but *do not forget* to sanitize / whitelist the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some verifications in order to forbid SQL injections, the easiest way is to format the query string with the user input.

```py
db.execute ("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE person = {};".format(user_input))
```

And the content of `user_input` would be placed on the curly brackets.

It's not very clear on how you're getting user input, though.

Comment: My question was about choosing the table not the person and btw I've just created this user_input for simplicity.(Instead of MyTable I want the user_input)

Comment: It's the same idea, you just need to replace it with curly brackets: `db.execute ("SELECT number FROM {} WHERE person = 1;".format(user_input))`

Comment: Thanks, I wish I can upvote your question. Anyway Thanks